# Behavior of double exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> I am trying to show
>   $$\sum_{n \ge 0} 2^{-2^n/m} \lesssim \sqrt{m},$$
>   up to constant factors. Here $m \ge 1$.

Attempts/thoughts:

- If I try to do an integral approximation, I get $\int_0^\infty 2^{-2^x/m} \mathop{dx}$ which I do not know how to handle either.
- We could try to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \sum_{n \ge 0} 2^{-2^n/m}$ (or, after a change of variables $M^2=m$, we can consider $\frac{1}{M} \sum_{n \ge 0} 2^{-2^n/M^2}$) converges to a constant as $m \to \infty$ (or $M \to \infty$), but these reformulations did not help me either.
- If I bound the series crudely with $\sum_{k \ge 0} 2^{-k/m}$, the resulting rate $\frac{1}{1 - 2^{-1/m}}$ is too large I believe.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just speculating: Condensation Test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: What does this symbol $\lesssim$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding and correcting sranthrop's answer:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-2^n/m}
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^n f(2^n)\\
&\leq2\sum_{n\geq1}f(n)\\
&=2\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a^n}{n}\\
&=-2\log(1-a)\\
&=-2\log(1-2^{-1/m})\\
&=-2\log(1-e^{-\log 2/m})\\
&\approx -2\log(1-(1-\log 2/m))\\
&=- 2\log(\log 2/m)\\
&= -2(\log(\log 2)-\log(m))\\
&\approx 2\log(m)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore the sum is
$O(\log m)$
which is
$O(m^c)$
for any $c > 0$,
not just $c = \frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $a:=2^{-1/m}$ and $f(n)=a^n/n$. Then by the Cauchy Condensation Test we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-2^n/m}=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^n f(2^n)\leq2\sum_{n\geq1}f(n)=2\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a^n}{n}=2\log\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)=2\log\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{-1/m}}\right).
\end{align}
Moreover,
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{-1/m}}\right)\to0,\quad m\to\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: That's $1-a$, not $a-1$. I submitted a corrected and expanded answer based on yours, which I, of course, upvoted.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I mixed $a$ and $1/a$ up. Sry about that, and thanks for pointing this out.